# Modifying form fields with FieldEditingControls

Tags: c#, kentico

I’m trying to add a honey pot field to our contact us form. When I add hidden field to the form via the Kentico GUI (with conditions making it invisible) it’s not available in the source so I don’t think it will actually work. However I also tried adding the form via the GUI and trying modify the style on prerender in my form control won’t work either (Code below). It is odd as it will actually let me change the value of the field in my form control but not the styling. Is this typical of Kentico and is there a solution to trying to implement a honeypot field? I had suggested we just add more validation methods to the form, but I was told that they want the same behavior as the existing forms.

Here is the method I’m using.
((CMS.FormControls.EditingFormControl)viewBiz.BasicForm.FieldEditingControls["Pooh"]).Style.Add("display", "none");

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the advanced properties of the field input, you should be able to apply styles to the input. You could set display:none; there to hide it from the user, but still have it available in the source.

Comment: I feel a little stupid now. I didn't even think about putting my properties into those fields... Thanks.

Comment: @user1040975 It's not completely obvious that they're there in the first place. Nothing to feel stupid about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also going to create a form control for this so that it can easily be applied to another with some validation functionality (i.e. a redirect to captcha)